# Django - How to display specific content in a template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Django newbie question - I need to display a specific entry in a template. So far I have not been able to get this to work. I have the following code:

model:

```
class BasicPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = HTMLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

view:

```
class TermsPageView(TemplateView):
    model = BasicPage
    template_name = 'terms.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        body = BasicPage.objects.filter(id=1)
        return body
```

template:

```
{% block content %} 

<h1>{{ body.title }}</h1>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass this object as a context, you need to use [**`get_context_data`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data):

```
class TermsPageView(TemplateView):
    model = BasicPage
    template_name = 'terms.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['body'] = BasicPage.objects.get(id=1)
        return context
```

Note that this is using `get` so you will only get one object. But if you really want to use a queryset (if you use `filter`), then you need to iterate through the list as @May.D has indicated.

Comment: This probably makes the most sense since I only want to return one object.

Answer (score 1):

We would need more information to solve this issue, but I guess that, as `get_queryset` returns a QuerySet which is an iterable, to display body in you template you need to use a for loop :

```
{% block content %} 
{% for i in body %}
<h1>{{ i.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Anyway, using `TemplateView` to return a single item `filter(id=1)` seems to indicate that you need to deep digger in documentation, this kind of view aims to be generic, not return a single item with unique ID.